# For every AJAX call I make, I would like to reload a new java-script

Tags: javascript

Basically, everytime anybody does anything on this website, I need to retrieve a new javascript from the server (it is a complex math thing, and I am not concerned with speed).

I make the AJAX call, and stick it in the browser in a  tag, like this:

```
getandplaceajax('id=showtotals','main');   // The first is the URL parameter, and the second is the ID of the <div> tag.
```

While I am doing this, I would like to re-write the java-script file, on the server, and then reload it. It is like this, in the  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="randomfilename.js"></script>
```

After this I refresh my object thusly, by retreiving new XML data:

```
    object1.loadXML("http://mywebsite/mydata.xml",
       function(xml, url) {eventSource.loadXML(xml,url); });
```

How do I tell the browser to re-load the java-script file (force a re-load, on demand)?

I tried to interactively  load the java-script into the  portion of the page, but this is an iffy situation given that AJAX is asynchronous and unpredictable in the event chain.

And I am not doing page loads, so referencing the java-script with a unique number parameter (to prevent caching)  isn't an option.

An extra $50 in the church offering plate next Sunday, in your name, for a solution.

Thanks in advance

Jeff

Comment: what is the relation between page page load and referencing your script by a random number.

Comment: is the javascript you require, mostly logic code or only values. The former seems more complicated to debug and prone to errors ,rather than using JSONs objects, or all datas ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make an Ajax call if you just need to load a JavaScript file. You can just append a new script tag to the page.

```
var scr = document.createElement("script");
scr.type="text/javascript";
scr.src="myFile.js";
document.body.appendChild(scr)
```

If you are calling the same file each time you need to force it to fetch the new file by adding a querystring value

```
scr.src="myFile.js?ts=" + new Date().getTime();
```

On the server you can request a php, servlet, .NET page, etc and have it return the JavaScript code. It does not have to be a js file. Just set the content type to be JavaScript and your browser will not care.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any library, you can use what Facebook is doing

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

```
var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
e.src = document.location.protocol +
  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
```

to load in a new script this way.  You can also change the `src` of the script tag, to something like `'myfile.js?timestamp=' + (new Date()).getTime()`, or you can return javascript with `<script>` tag around it and put it into a div or return javascript and eval them, similar to how RJS is handled.